# How can I print data from axios promise to my db in differents lines

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js

I'm currently having a problem.
I am making an axios request to my db and when I have retrieved the data, I would like to put it in a select form. I got a successful response, but I am getting the result in only one line. I've tried to put a `"\n"` in my .php file, but I'm always getting in one line. Strangely when I see the console.log im getting the data split by `"\n"` (and so every item of my request is in a different line, like I want)

Could you maybe help me with this? Here is some of my code, so that you will understand better.

Thank you !

```
In PHP request file:

   $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT LanguageFrenchName FROM language");

   while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){

    foreach ($row as $item) {

        echo("\n".$item);

    }
}


In Vue.js file:

methods:{
    getter_langues: function () {
                    axios.get('requete_langues.php')
                        .then(function (response) {
                            get_langues.langues = response.data;
                            console.log (response.data);
                        })
                        .catch(function (error) {
                            console.log(error);
                        });
                }
            },




![expected result showed in console.log] (https://i.ibb.co/kKQkH6Q/Capture3.png)
![actual result showed in one line in select form] (https://i.ibb.co/QXGhWs0/Capture5.png)
```

Comment: Add `.split(' ')` to the end of the response data,you should end up with: `get_langues.langues = response.data.split(' ');`

Comment: @samroberts707 I strongly advise against this solution. What if your data contains spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API should return a response in standard format e.g. JSON or XML. JSON is obviously the preferred one since you use JavaScript. Check out this tutorial on how to convert your data to JSON in PHP: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp

Comment: I actually did another thing, its not the best but I get what i want. But I used your answer because its easy to manipulate objects in Json format ! thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You should definitively use the `JSON` format !
But if you still want to use the `"\n"` way of doing it, you can with a `<pre>` html tag.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

example :

```
<template>
  <pre> {{ foo }} </pre>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      foo: "a\nb\nc"
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

result

```
a
b
c
```